# Posting Mongoose Complex Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

**Hello there**

I've got this Mongoose Schema (I know there is something wrong there), the important bit is the "**region**" part of it.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const destination = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true }, 
      flag: String,
      creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      region: { id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region' }, name: String },
}, {strict: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Destination', destination);
```

I'm posting using this form:

```html
<form action="/destinations" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="destination[name]">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="destination[name]" placeholder="Destination name...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="destination[name]">Flag</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="destination[flag]" placeholder="Destination flag...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="destination[region]">Region</label>
    <select class="form-control mb-4" name="region[name]]">
      <option selected disabled hidden>Choose a region</option>
      <% allRegions.forEach(region => { %>
        <option value="<%= region.name %>">
          <%= region.name %>
        </option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Add</button>

</form>
```

All data is being correctly posted to the Node.js file that processes it, however I can't find a way to save the "region id", this is how is being processed right now:

```
exports.destinations_create = (req, res) => {
  req.body.destination.region = { name: req.body.region.name };
  Destination.create(req.body.destination)
  .then(newDestination => {
    Regions.findOne({name: req.body.region.name})
    .then(foundRegion => {
      newDestination.region.id = foundRegion._id;
      foundRegion.countries.push(newDestination._id);
      foundRegion.save();
    });
    res.redirect('/destinations');
  })
  .catch(err => res.redirect('/'));
}
```

I thought I could leave the id empty and then add it later, as it is just an object, but nothing works, any ideas of what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could leave id as well as name property of region since you are referencing Region.

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

     const destination = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true }, 
      flag: String,
      creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      region: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region' });
      module.exports = mongoose.model('Destination', destination);
```

and then in your add method:

```
     exports.destination_create = async(req,res)=>{
    const region = await Region.findOne({name: req.body.region});
    const destination = new Destination({
     region: region._id,
    name: req.body.name,
    flag: req.body.flag
})
await destination.save();
res.redirect('/destination');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure if I'm understanding or explaining this well, the goal is to have both, the id and the name of the region embedded in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda found a solution, and I say kinda because I am not sure about how efficient it is memory wise but:

Model **destination** was changed:

```
region: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region' },
```

And then what I did was to "**deep populate**" the regions query:

```
Regions.find({})
  .select('_id name image countries')
  .populate({
    path: 'countries',
    model: 'Destination',
    populate: {
      path: 'cities',
      model: 'City'
    }
  }).then(...).catch(...);
```